# How to update a GridView on a page from a Settings Charm Flyout?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a page with a GridView. One of my Settings Charm entries can initialize that page, i.e. the Setting Charm can either remove or load the GridView entries. If I start the Setting Charm while on this page, and initialize the GridView, when I close the Setting Charm the GridView stays in the same state as before the initialization, i.e. it displays the same entries. If I move back a page and then forward to that page again, the page updates its content correctly, but I have to do this un-attractive move back and forward.

How can I avoid it?

Thanks,
EitanB

Comment: That depends totally on how you are doing whatever you are doing. You need to share more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you use `ObservableCollection` for the item's in `GridView` or simple `List`, if not you use `ObservableCollection` instead.